# Angular 2+ preserve whitespaces with ngmodel on textarea

Tags: angular, textarea

I'm trying to write a simple text editor with fixed columns to configure the footer of a fiscal printer.
I'm using a plain textarea to do this and I catch every key pressed to check the text length.
I have also 3 buttons to set the alignment of the text.
So if I want to align the text centered I put whitespaces on both sides of the text so it appear centered.
**This working fine.**
But when I try to get the textarea value from my ngmodel I lost whitespaces and my text is not centered anymore.
Here is an example to show the strange behaviour.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w9njit?file=src/app/app.component.html

If I do the same with plain javascript it's working without problem.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-splvb2?file=index.js

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using angular, you should avoid accessing the native element itself. set the formatted string to your model property instead of the native input. angular will take care and update the textarea with the binding for you.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-fvtcp3?file=src/app/app.component.ts